# Как решить проблему с дублированием кода в дочерних классах?

Tags: php, ооп, архитектура

Есть абстрактный класс `MaterialValue`:

```
abstract class MaterialValue
{
  public function __construct($model){...}

  protected static function find($id)
  {
    $model = OtherClass::find($id);
    if($model)
      return $model
    return false;

  }
}
```

Изначально задача стоит, чтобы класс, после успешного поиска, возвращал собственный экземпляр, поэтому дочерние классы содержат такой код:

класс `Product`:

```
class Product extends MaterialValue
{
    public static function find($id)
    {
        $material = parent::find($id);

        if($material)
            return new self($material);
        return false;
    }
}
```

И класс `Ingredient`:

```
class Ingredient extends MaterialValue
    {
        public static function find($id)
        {
            $material = parent::find($id);

            if($material)
                return new self($material);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Код метода `find` идентичен. Возникает вопрос, каким образом избежать такого дублирования?

Comment: в базовом классе `return new static($model);`

Comment: @vp_arth Круто, спасибо! Напишите ответ, пожалуйста, чтобы я мог его отметить.

Comment: @RostD Может, я чего-то не понимаю, но что за `OtherClass` у вас тут?

Comment: @RostD И почему в классе-родителе `protected function find($id)`, а не `protected static function find($id)`?

Comment: @Станислав OtherClass это класс, не имеющий значения в данном примере, просто обозначение, что производятся какие-то действия с помощью внешнего кода.

Comment: @Станислав на счет static верно подмечено, изменил

Comment: @RostD, ага. Кстати есть еще вариант с trait, в который можно было бы вынести код дублирующейся функции, и использовать его потом, подключая в классах-наследниках.

Comment: @Станислав тоже думал над этим вариантом, но отказался, т.к. считаю, что трейты  все таки должны использоваться для более масштабных и общих вещей, таких как ведение логов, сбор эксепшенов и т.п.

Comment: @RostD, ну, это уже дело вкуса, просто возможно, что вариант с ними будет понятнее в будущем для поддержки кода, и тд и тп, да и просто потомкам напоминание ;) Успехов.

Вообще же, меня тут смущает обращение к стороннему классу в классе-родителе, как-то это неправильно изначально, на мой вкус. Но это тема для чата уже скорее.

Comment: @Станислав верно сказано, поэтому в итоге я решил вопрос с помощью паттерна "Фабрика"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать позднее статическое связывание:

```
abstract class MaterialValue
{
  public function __construct($model){...}

  protected static function find($id)
  {
    $model = OtherClass::find($id);
    if($model)
      return new static($model);
    return false;

  }
}
```

Вообще, главное взять за правило, что возвращаемый тип метода не должен меняться в наследниках.
Если в дочерних классах планируется возвращать экземпляр `MaterialValue`, то и родительский метод должен возвращать его же.